# Docker image with aws-cli v2 and dind, based on Alpine:3.11

Tags: docker, aws-cli, alpine-linux

Hi I'm struggling creating a Docker image with aws-cli v2 and Docker, based on Alpine:3.11

I'm using the following commands:

```
FROM docker:stable #docker is based on Alpine

RUN apk add curl && \
    curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && \
    ./aws/install

RUN aws --version && docker -v
```

I'm obtaining an output like this:

```
Step 6/6 : RUN aws --version && docker -v
 ---> Running in 5015c32e62fe
/bin/sh: aws: Permission denied
The command '/bin/sh -c aws --version && docker -v' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

This is a strange behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AWS binaries won't work on docker images based on Alpine because they are compiling them against glibc.

Two solutions:

1. build it from `ubuntu:latest`
2. Use this Dockerfile which adds glibc and then removes some stuff

```
FROM alpine:3.11

ENV GLIBC_VER=2.31-r0

RUN apk --no-cache add \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && curl -sL https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
        glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && curl -sL https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip -o awscliv2.zip \
    && unzip awscliv2.zip \
    && aws/install \
    && rm -rf \
        awscliv2.zip \
        aws \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/*/dist/aws_completer \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/*/dist/awscli/data/ac.index \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/*/dist/awscli/examples \
    && apk --no-cache del \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && rm glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && rm glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN apk add docker

RUN aws --version && docker --version
```

Comment: I love alpine, but recommend sticking with glibc based distros when necessary.

Comment: Sure is better, but in a CI/CD context I prefer to privilege a smaller image. With this configuration I'm obtaining a 122MB image.

Comment: I also needed to add `apk del libc6-compat` due to `ERROR: glibc-2.31-r0: trying to overwrite lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 owned by libc6-compat-1.2.2-r7`

Comment: How are you configuring the aws cli? i.e pass credentials file or envvars directly